# Query About Hadoop Behavior

Tags: hadoop

I was having a discussion with one of my seniors and he put up a question like this:

Suppose I am having a Hadoop job that takes about 15 days to complete and on the 14th day the NameNode goes down.
Now we don't want to lose all the processing that has been done as this process cannot be repeated again due to time restrictions.

1. So what is the process/what happens if the NameNode goes down? What happens to the processing?
2. Do I lose all the processing on the data that has happened so far?
3. Do the job resume from the point where the NameNode had failed?
4. In case there is a hardware issue and I need to issue a new machine for the NameNode, will it resume the job from the point the earlier NameNode failed?

PS-> This is not a High Availability NameNode

Comment: I think I found the answer to my own question:
http://www.cloudera.com/content/cloudera-content/cloudera-docs/CDH4/4.5.0/CDH4-Security-Guide/cdh4sg_topic_3_14.html
Forcing the secondary namenode to put a checkpoint forcefully by giving a time period will help me sync the namenode again after a namenode failure.